# Ghostscript doesn't generate pdf

Tags: windows, batch-file, ghostscript

I've a problem with that command line :

`gswin32c.exe -sDevice=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf -dNOPROMPT -dNODISPLAY -dNOPAUSE doc.prn-q -c quit`

The program runs without any error.If I enable the display option, i can see the Ghostscript image of my document but my PDF is not generated.

Any Ideas ?

***Solved***

`gswin32c -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=doc.pdf doc.prn -c quit`

Comment: `Any Ideas ?` of course: you should explain clearly what happens with your command line, what was the result, what was expected, error messages: the whole stuff. My comment contains more words than your question `:/`

Comment: Message edited. I've finally found the problem. thank you for taking time to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command line includes `'doc.prn-q'` possibly you meant `'doc.prn -q'`. Hint, if you are trying to debug a problem, *don't* turn off all the messages which might be trying to give you information! (`-q` is 'quiet' mode).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, maybe parameters where not well placed in my command line.

`gswin32c -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=doc.pdf doc.prn -c quit`

Thank you for all guys !
Have a nice day
Fabien